# No screen messages from BIOS after discrete graphics card installation

Tags: windows-xp, boot, bios, graphics

My old PC used to work fine with onboard graphics, but eventually (I think) that was slowing down the whole system. So I decided to add a discrete graphics board - after that I don't see any output from the motherboard BIOS during the system boot. For example - no message "Press DEL to enter BIOS setup", no messages when I try to boot from CDROM etc. I see only dark screen and then, after ~30 seconds, my OS login screen.

What can I try to get the BIOS output back?

- Motherboard: ASUS M4A78-PRO
- Graphics board: ASUS GT710
- OS: Windows XP (yes!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you wish to enter BIOS and I assume DEL is the only key that gets you there. It is usually enough to press that key (DEL in your case) repeteadly during booting phase of the PC.

Comment: I tried repeated DEL pressing many times and didn't get into BIOS. Also when booting from CDROM I'm required to press Enter at some moment - l never guessed that moment correctly cause the screen doesn't show anything

Comment: Since your system boots correctly everything is fine with your BIOS. And I assume once in Windows, system is using newly installed discrete GPU. POST messages are probably shadowed by some BIOS setting, Quick BOOT is probable culprit in that case. Or maybe your system is confused by new graphic card while it boots. 

So, if you can not manage to enter BIOS with DEL during POST you will probably have to take GPU out and change BIOS settings before reinstalling it.

Comment: By changing BIOS settings I mean settings that regulate order in which system uses video card...probbaly Primary Video Controller or something similar.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to disable the onboard graphics in BIOS

Comment: Make sure you choose your GPU as primary graphic card.

Comment: Thanks, I've finally found the BIOS setting to make the discrete graphics board the primary one - all works now